# Azure Artifacts Feed is much slower than maven central

Tags: azure, maven, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm working on a project in Azure DevOps and, as recommended in the doc, I created an Artifacts Feed with maven central as upstream source to store all my dependencies (I don't really need to publish artifacts for now).

So I configured my local maven to fetch all the dependencies from my feed instead of maven central and it all works fine, except that it's very slow compared to maven central.

When I start from an empty .m2 on my local machine, it takes 1 min 15 secs to build my project when downloading the dependencies from maven central, but it takes over 8 minutes to do the same when downloading the dependencies from the Feed (which contains already all the dependencies).

I could live with that, since the download of everything happens only on the first build.

But the issue is that it's also slower when building my project from Azure Pipelines, which I really didn't expect since it's a connection from Azure to Azure and within the same organization. In this case, it takes at least twice the time when using the feed rather than maven central. And this will be true every time since Azure Pipelines gives you a fresh VM each time you build (I'm using a hosted agent), so there's no dependencies caching in this case.

It's really annoying since my project is just a HelloWorld so far, so it will only get worse over time.

Using a repository manager/feed is the best practice according to both Maven and Azure, but at this point I'm really thinking of going for the bad practice of getting everything from maven central instead of my feed, at least in my pipeline, to improve the performance.

Am I the only one having this issue ? What are your thoughts about this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, after diving into the documentation for Azure Pipelines recently, I found out there is a way to cache the maven repository between runs so it partially solves my issue since the full download of the dependencies will happen only once.
[Here is the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/caching?view=azure-devops) in question for those who are interested.