# Speed up Azure feed / artifact download

Tags: azure-devops

We are using an Azure Feed as Maven repository. It works, but downloading artifacts is always somewhere between 100~300 kBps. If there is any way to speed this up, I would like to know.

It almost looks as if this is throttled on purpose, because it is consistently slow over the weeks and months that I'm using it.

N.B. There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62387138/azure-artifacts-feed-is-much-slower-than-maven-central), but it is for downloading within the Azure cloud, whereas mine is for downloading out of the cloud.

Edit: As requested by Leo Lui-MSFT, this is how I download the artifacts:

1. In a web browser, I click on the Azure Artifacts icon on the bottom left in one of my projects (although this is an organization-scoped feed)
2. choose an item from the list of (Maven) packages
3. click on one of the items in the "Files" list
4. wait

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Speed up Azure feed / artifact download

Azure devops does not limit the speed when download artifacts. You could use the hosted agent to build your pipeline to check whether the rate is limited.

If you are using a private proxy, your download speed limit may be related to your network itself or your proxy. You could check it with another network.

Besides, you could also use the Pipeline caching to cache those artifacts to your local, so that help reduce build time by allowing the outputs or downloaded dependencies from one run to be reused in later runs.

Comment: Azure feeds are consistently slow, regardless from what network - here in Tokyo - I tried. With many or most other downloads, speed is at a 10 MByte/sec or more. I don't know if the location has something to do with it, but even private wired internet connections in Tokyo are - and have been for at least 15 years - at least at 100Mbit/s. Company links are still better of course.

Comment: @EvgeniyBerezovsky, Thanks for your quickly reply. In this case, have you tried run your pipeline with hosted agent to check the download speed?

Comment: This is not about downloading as part of a pipeline, it is about downloading artifacts built with a pipeline. Maybe the in-cloud bandwidth is different, but I'm trying to get artifacts out of the cloud.

Comment: @EvgeniyBerezovsky, I know that, I just want to confirm if this issue is related to the network and proxy. BTW, how did you download artifacts, would you please share your task configuration to us in you question?

Comment: I edited my question to describe the download process, which is manual, using a browser.

Comment: @EvgeniyBerezovsky, Thanks, Do you mean that the speed of downloading packages manually is very slow? Obviously this is because of the limitation of your network access to azure resources. In my area, if I do not connect to the VPN, my access to azure resources is also very slow. When I use vpn to download the package, I will get the full bandwidth.

Comment: Read my first comment again. No, the networks I'm using are fine, and - depending on the server in question - often magnitudes faster. I do know how to compare the speed of downloads. I do know the implications of connecting via slow links or not. When you say "full bandwidth", what is that in absolute numbers?

Comment: I know that there is no problem with your internet speed. The problem is that the network in your area will be restricted when accessing MS resources. As in the area where I am now, my access to Microsoft resources is very slow, and I have to resort to VPN.

Comment: I don't know what the reason is - sometimes downloads are at Mbit/sec, but almost always they are not. In the same environment.

Comment: Azure Artifacts is exceedingly slow even when running MS hosted agents within their own datacenters, for example 4GB takes over 4 minutes to download. So don't assume it's your own connection.